# Ajax: I need to pass the value from php script file to html file

Tags: ajax

I need to get the value from the PHP script file to HTML in ajax. Need to append the response condition wise.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var collectionarrayValues = <?php echo json_encode($subcatId); ?>;
            $.each(collectionarrayValues, function(index, value) {
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>ajax/index/shopallnew/collection/'+value;
                $.ajax({
                        //async: false,
                        url:ajaxurl,
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'HTML',
                        beforeSend: function () { showLoader(); },
                        success:function(response){
                        if (response != '')
                        {
                            hideLoader();
                            jQuery(".appendCollection").removeClass("load");
                            jQuery('.appendCollection').append(response);

                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I want to add the condition like this

```
if(data ==test1){
    jQuery('.appendCollection1').append(response);
}else if(data ==test2){
    jQuery('.appendCollection2').append(response);
}


Test1 and test2 will come from PHP file
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem then? Did you try and get any error?

Comment: How to pass the value from PHP server file to HTML with ajax?

Comment: I think it is what you do there. Change the type to `GET`. Your code is not very clear. Where is `data` from?